# $ {L}_{1} $ (L1) Norm Regularized Minimization with of Convex Function with Linear Equality Constraint Using ADMM Framework

Tags: optimization, convex-optimization, constraints, regularization

In section 6.3 of [Distributed Optimization and Statistical Learning via the Alternating Direction Method of Multipliers](https://web.stanford.edu/%7Eboyd/papers/pdf/admm_distr_stats.pdf) there is a method for minimizing a loss function with l1 regularization. i.e.

minimize $l(\bf{x})+\lambda||x||_1$

How can I add the equality constraint

$\sum\limits_{i} x_i =1$ for such a problem and perform the optimization ?

Comment: Do you need an ADMM Solution for that?

Comment: That is the solution I was hoping to at the time I posted this. However later on I took a different approach for my research problem, so I did not have solve this particular problem. Anyway I would like to see a solution if there is any.

Comment: Can I, for the ADMM ocde, use $ l \left( x \right) = \frac{1}{2} \left\| A x - b \right\|_{2}^{2} $? Later on you'll replace it with what you need.

Comment: Have a look at - [Prox Operator of L1 Norm with Linear Equality Constraint (Sum of Elements)](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2886713).

Answer (score 1):

One approach could be to rewrite it as $$\sum_i x_i - 1 = 0$$ which motivates adding the following penalty term $$\lambda_S\left\|\sum_i x_i - 1\right\|_k = \lambda_S\|{\bf Sx} - 1\|_k$$ for some suitable $k$ where $\bf S$ is a matrix for the sum operator. Basically a dot product between x vector and a vector of ones. The equality will be true when the thing inside the norm is equal to 0. Which norm $k$ we choose ( and maybe the size of a scalar weight like $\lambda_S$ ) will determine how important that it is exactly 0.

Comment: Thank you, that is what I also had in my mind. Since I have seen closed form solutions (like Lagrangians) to other conventional optimization problems with this type of a equality constraint, I though there can be a straight forward method to include the constraint.

Answer (score 1):

You have 2 options here:

1. Solve the problem using ADMM and transform $ \left\| x \right\|_{1} $ into $ \left\| z \right\|_{1} $ (Classic LASSO ADMM). In the $ x $ update step add projection onto the set by $ x = x - \frac{ \boldsymbol{1}^{T} x - 1 }{n} \boldsymbol{1} $ which is the orthogonal projection onto the set.
2. Solve a different ADMM when adding $ I_{\mathcal{S}} \left( z \right) $ which is the Indicator function of the set $ \mathcal{S} $ as defined above. This means you'll have ADMM which on one iteration solve LASSO problem with reagridng to $ x $ (Actually LASSO with [Tikhonov Regularization](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tikhonov_regularization), which is called [Elastic Net Regularization](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Elastic_net_regularization)) and on the other, regarding $ z $ you will have a projection operation (As in (1)).

Clearly the first approach is much easier.
If you want a code, let me know.