# Proximal Operator / Mapping of $ {L}_{1} $ Norm with Linear Equality Constraint (Sum of Elements)

Tags: convex-optimization, least-squares, proximal-operators

How could one solve the following problem:

$$ \operatorname{Prox}_{\gamma f \left( \cdot \right)} \left( y \right) = \arg \min_{x} \frac{1}{2} {\left\| x - y \right\|}_{2}^{2} + \gamma {\left\| x \right\|}_{1} \quad \text{subject to} \; \boldsymbol{1}^{T} x = b $$

Namely, this is a Least Squares Problem with $ {L}_{1} $ Norm Regularization (LASSO) with Linear Equality (Sum) constraint:

$$\begin{aligned}
\arg \min_{x} \quad & \frac{1}{2} {\left\| x - y \right\|}_{2}^{2} + \gamma {\left\| x \right\|}_{1} \\
\text{subject to} \quad & \boldsymbol{1}^{T} x = b
\end{aligned}$$

Comment: Related to [L1 (L1) Norm Regularized Minimization with of Convex Function with Linear Equality Constraint Using ADMM Framework](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1612610).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is given by:

$$\begin{aligned}
\arg \min_{x} \quad & \frac{1}{2} {\left\| x - y \right\|}_{2}^{2} + \gamma {\left\| x \right\|}_{1} \\
\text{subject to} \quad & \boldsymbol{1}^{T} x = b
\end{aligned}$$

The Lagrangian is given by:

$$ L \left( x, \beta \right) = \frac{1}{2} {\left\| x - y \right\|}_{2}^{2} + \gamma {\left\| x \right\|}_{1} + \beta \left( \boldsymbol{1}^{T} x - b \right) $$

The solution must obey KKT Conditions (The problem is Convex and Slater Conditions are satisfied) which are given by:

$$\begin{align*}
    \nabla L \left( x, \beta \right) = x - y + \gamma \partial {\left\| x \right\|}_{1} + \beta \boldsymbol{1} & = 0 & \text{(1)} \\
    \boldsymbol{1}^{T} x & = b & \text{(2)} \\
\end{align*}$$

From (1) is is clear that $ x = \operatorname{Prox}_{ \gamma {\left\| \cdot \right\|}_{1} } \left( y - \beta \boldsymbol{1} \right) $ (As a shifted solution to the [$ {L}_{1} $ Prox](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1961888)). Using (2) one would get:

$$ \boldsymbol{1}^{T} \operatorname{Prox}_{ \gamma {\left\| \cdot \right\|}_{1} } \left( y - \beta \boldsymbol{1} \right) = b \Rightarrow b - \boldsymbol{1}^{T} \operatorname{Prox}_{ \gamma {\left\| \cdot \right\|}_{1} } \left( y - \beta \boldsymbol{1} \right) = 0 $$
Using the explicit solution of $ \operatorname{Prox}_{ \gamma {\left\| \cdot \right\|}_{1} } \left( \cdot \right) $ as the Soft Threshold operator yields:

$$ g \left( \beta \right) = \sum_{i = 1}^{n} \operatorname{sign} \left( {y}_{i} - \beta \right) { \left( \left| {y}_{i} - \beta \right| - \gamma \right) }_{+} - b $$

Now the problem becomes finding the root of the function $ g \left( \beta \right) $ and the plug it into the Prox.

This is (The function $ g \left( \beta \right) $) a monotonic decreasing function of $ \beta $ which we're looking for its zero (Which solves the problem).
One could solve this within any 1D solver within the range $ \left[ \max(y) + b, \min(y) - b \right] $ which must contain zero.

More efficient approach is based on the fast this is a Piece Wise Linear function (Of $ \beta $) with break points at $ \left| {y}_{i} - \beta \right| = \gamma $ (Hence there are $ 2 n $ points).
Hence by utilizing Bi-Section method which moves the points within the sorted $ 2 n $ break points one could easily find the section which the function has constant slope within it and have the zero value in it.
Let's mark this section by $ \left[ {\beta}_{min}, {\beta}_{max} \right] $, then $ \forall {\beta}_{i}, {\beta}_{j} \in \left[ {\beta}_{min}, {\beta}_{max} \right] : \; \operatorname{sign} \left( y - {\beta}_{i} \right) = \operatorname{sign} \left( y - {\beta}_{j} \right) = e $.  This also implies that the support, $ \mathcal{S} = \left\{ i \mid { \left( \left| {y}_{i} - \beta \right| - \gamma \right) }_{+} \neq 0 \right\} $ is constant within this section (As otherwise a new break point would be created).

This means the equation becomes:

$$\begin{aligned}
0 & = \sum_{i \in \mathcal{S}} {e}_{i} \left( \left| {y}_{i} - \beta \right| - \gamma \right) - b & \text{} \\
& = \sum_{i \in \mathcal{S}} {y}_{i} - \beta - \gamma {e}_{i} - b & \text{ $ {e}_{i} \left| {y}_{i} - \beta \right| = \operatorname{sign} \left( {y}_{i} - \beta \right) \left| {y}_{i} - \beta \right|= {y}_{i} - \beta $ } \\
& \Rightarrow \sum_{i \in \mathcal{S}} \beta = \sum_{i \in \mathcal{S}} {y}_{i} - \sum_{i \in \mathcal{S}} \gamma {e}_{i} - b & \text{} \\
& \Rightarrow \beta = \frac{1}{ \left| \mathcal{S} \right| } \left( \sum_{i \in \mathcal{S}} \left( {y}_{i} - \gamma {e}_{i} \right) - b \right)
\end{aligned}$$

The full MATLAB code with CVX validation is available in my [StackExchnage Mathematics Q2886713 GitHub Repository](https://github.com/RoyiAvital/StackExchangeCodes).

**Remark**
Knowing the solution to the above problem (Deriving the Prox Operator) gives us an efficient method (Proximal Gradient Descent) to solve:

$$\begin{aligned}
\arg \min_{x} \quad & \frac{1}{2} {\left\| A x - b \right\|}_{2}^{2} + \gamma {\left\| x \right\|}_{1} \\
\text{subject to} \quad & \boldsymbol{1}^{T} x = b
\end{aligned}$$

With the ADMM framework we can even tackle more general cases.

**Reference**
The solution is based on [Efficient Solvers for Sparse Subspace Clustering](https://arxiv.org/abs/1804.06291).